# Visual Studio 2010 and Moss 2007 issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2007

Here is the scenario: My dev environment is a Windows 2003 virtual server, MOSS2007, VS 2008, SQL2005, .net Framework 3.5, Ajax 2.0.

We're in the process of upgrading user workstations to Win 7. So I decided to install VS 2010 alongside VS2008.

When I tried to open an existing VS2008 project that has custom web parts for the MOSS, it went through the upgrade wizard but at the end it failed but I did not note what the error was. Instead, I decided to recreate the project but when adding a new sharepoint webpart to my solution I received an error stating that SharePoint must be forst installed on the server. Well lah-di-dah, it is installed!!! So now what?

Ended up uninstalling VS2010, but that is not the point. Does VS2010 requires SharePoint 2010 to work, really? Can anyone elaborate on this. Thanks.

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled both versions of VS and that soleved the problem. (not the most efficient method, however).

Answer (score 0):

You tried to open up a Sharepoint solution on your new Windows 7 workstation? I doubt you've got Sharepoint installed on that workstation, so the error message might be correct when it's saying Sharepoint isn't installed.

But, you can use VS2010 to do some Sharepoint 2007 development, as written here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/bbced82a-a0e2-4a50-836a-3deb96c02de8
You still might want to have WSPBuilder installed though, even though VS2010 works pretty slick out of the box.

Comment: No not on Window 7 workstation. On the W2003 server which has MOSS2007 installed.